Give "Human Reading" order to bounding boxes (Sort Bounding Box)
I want to sort bounding boxes in a way that a human would read a document using python.
Context:
I have a PDF document and I am using unilm DiT (Document image Transformer) to know which parts are text, tittle, figures etc...

The program I have give me the bounding boxes. Each one is [x1,y1,x2,y2].
Here is a list of lists of all the document bounding boxes:
[array([[ 103.02899 ,  161.3142  ,  217.45796 ,  210.22182 ],
        [ 130.74086 ,  221.4759  , 1135.7678  , 1308.4152  ],
        [ 133.87976 ,  217.02632 ,  564.2497  ,  244.9154  ],
        [ 130.62425 ,  221.49861 , 1135.455   , 1308.6006  ],
        [ 138.23459 ,  944.16144 ,  933.1107  ,  971.11053 ],
        [ 135.89749 ,  266.74066 ,  500.9009  ,  294.21164 ],
        [ 137.03072 ,  316.2809  ,  451.60605 ,  341.6856  ],
        [ 165.17134 , 1138.6821  , 1078.7845  , 1165.598   ],
        [ 164.21489 , 1041.0151  , 1080.4374  , 1068.1696  ],
        [ 163.1837  ,  362.7967  ,  665.3587  ,  390.78964 ],
        [ 133.21732 , 1283.8135  ,  714.98627 , 1310.27    ],
        [ 163.69078 ,  992.2993  , 1139.0627  , 1020.0374  ],
        [ 164.48352 ,  896.2904  ,  613.3585  ,  923.83417 ],
        [ 102.764984,  162.1042  ,  217.70555 ,  210.24873 ],
        [ 134.46411 ,  982.08826 , 1132.7267  , 1305.6736  ],
        [ 134.77502 ,  217.52219 ,  180.37938 ,  246.38625 ],
        [ 146.1119  ,  992.2667  , 1137.9609  , 1051.9343  ]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([[ 102.28195 , 1014.62805 , 1145.7059  , 1182.6556  ],
        [1200.8572  , 1051.0222  , 2242.135   , 1286.1064  ],
        [1200.9989  ,  849.6927  , 2243.6516  , 1017.17334 ],
        [1200.7759  , 1321.2921  , 2243.5608  , 1488.8195  ],
        [ 102.28653 ,  811.93085 , 1145.9602  ,  979.78326 ],
        [ 102.13058 , 1216.301   , 1146.1956  , 1350.133   ],
        [ 103.3674  ,  300.98322 , 1145.34    ,  433.19122 ],
        [ 101.8579  ,  575.4475  , 1145.2365  ,  778.31165 ],
        [ 102.313194, 1384.694   , 1143.1642  , 1450.8247  ],
        [ 102.4711  ,  505.24783 ,  565.6079  ,  540.7188  ],
        [ 101.352806,  235.11595 ,  668.7142  ,  270.44696 ],
        [1250.9564  ,  159.35565 , 2243.6643  ,  799.01953 ],
        [ 189.69292 , 1487.3816  , 1143.3586  , 1521.7859  ],
        [1251.2402  ,  698.2847  , 2243.356   ,  799.41016 ],
        [1254.0581  ,  161.61429 , 2240.995   ,  227.17094 ],
        [1253.1115  ,  631.6324  , 2055.2175  ,  664.33936 ],
        [1252.8674  ,  463.77487 , 2115.158   ,  496.47092 ],
        [1252.5759  ,  530.66144 , 2244.801   ,  597.82513 ],
        [1252.2747  ,  463.91608 , 2115.012   ,  496.5887  ],
        [1253.1115  ,  631.6324  , 2055.2175  ,  664.33936 ],
        [1252.5759  ,  530.66144 , 2244.801   ,  597.82513 ],
        [1252.3197  ,  360.84464 , 2243.9497  ,  428.37103 ],
        [1254.0581  ,  161.61429 , 2240.995   ,  227.17094 ],
        [1252.1666  ,  361.7382  , 2243.3171  ,  428.13202 ],
        [1252.9635  ,  262.75906 , 2243.745   ,  327.78656 ],
        [1251.2323  ,  698.1107  , 2242.7085  ,  799.2889  ],
        [1252.9635  ,  262.75906 , 2243.745   ,  327.78656 ],
        [ 109.83924 ,  577.66254 , 1145.1504  ,  609.7199  ]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([[ 102.82936 , 1215.7043  , 1145.3374  , 1485.9282  ],
        [ 103.086296,  946.20337 , 1145.0642  , 1182.5626  ],
        [1200.7762  ,  328.9661  , 2243.6682  ,  630.8703  ],
        [ 102.60216 ,  161.4006  , 1147.3835  ,  328.02734 ],
        [1201.0125  , 1056.1462  , 2243.5125  , 1223.4854  ],
        [ 102.53236 ,  363.47205 , 1145.8982  ,  530.163   ],
        [1201.2781  ,  160.79276 , 2243.2195  ,  294.73557 ],
        [ 102.507835,  564.884   , 1147.367   ,  765.5882  ],
        [1201.1653  ,  887.8552  , 2243.0154  , 1021.73645 ],
        [1200.687   , 1257.7191  , 2243.014   , 1392.5626  ],
        [1201.0906  ,  754.0313  , 2242.0107  ,  853.21783 ],
        [1201.0083  , 1427.1127  , 2243.0457  , 1493.9899  ],
        [ 103.28384 ,  875.4225  ,  704.6961  ,  913.94977 ],
        [ 103.364075,  805.68335 ,  508.36783 ,  840.49884 ],
        [1201.314   ,  664.91547 , 1615.8127  ,  703.4429  ]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([[1201.7263  ,  500.66977 , 2242.1575  ,  735.0437  ],
        [1201.1841  , 1242.5892  , 2243.3916  , 1408.6921  ],
        [1200.9933  , 1006.25726 , 2242.5823  , 1206.4875  ],
        [1201.1049  ,  771.1097  , 2243.707   ,  970.16406 ],
        [1201.0817  ,  312.51822 , 2241.7896  ,  377.04242 ],
        [ 102.998695, 1321.7573  , 1142.2418  , 1388.7323  ],
        [ 102.350624,  161.86537 , 1144.773   ,  226.75839 ],
        [ 108.749756,  282.9139  , 1151.8636  , 1246.8041  ],
        [1201.1393  , 1445.2106  , 2241.3794  , 1510.0906  ],
        [1201.9141  ,  428.46585 , 1463.2438  ,  466.56036 ],
        [ 103.51486 , 1423.0564  ,  650.9069  , 1522.9531  ],
        [1198.9916  ,  229.12599 , 1506.0461  ,  261.16162 ],
        [ 103.21208 , 1422.4965  ,  653.07404 , 1455.6022  ],
        [1200.5508  ,  161.8233  , 1588.3446  ,  193.85338 ],
        [1198.2754  ,  160.05194 , 1588.1744  ,  262.45444 ],
        [ 103.00852 , 1489.8982  ,  615.6249  , 1521.8049  ],
        [1200.3811  ,  161.77779 , 1587.9563  ,  193.65547 ],
        [1199.0402  ,  228.97342 , 1507.1224  ,  261.15698 ],
        [ 102.662605, 1488.5599  ,  615.30994 , 1521.6743  ],
        [1200.4636  ,  161.7385  , 1588.3782  ,  193.73279 ]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([[ 102.14204 , 1370.3859  , 1146.4833  , 1539.7417  ],
        [1201.0804  , 1240.6174  , 2243.5916  , 1442.6572  ],
        [1201.0663  ,  260.78265 , 2244.1123  ,  462.76047 ],
        [ 101.46868 , 1202.3933  , 1146.3353  , 1337.0488  ],
        [1200.5417  ,  971.47174 , 2243.78    , 1138.8203  ],
        [1201.2393  , 1476.6776  , 2243.7559  , 1543.3815  ],
        [1200.9918  ,  770.9383  , 2244.065   ,  869.2314  ],
        [1201.3623  ,  160.77377 , 2242.756   ,  226.57259 ],
        [1201.6224  ,  598.1692  , 2243.3855  ,  665.1867  ],
        [ 103.67328 ,  160.48311 , 1144.6067  , 1098.5085  ],
        [1201.4646  ,  496.55978 , 2243.4163  ,  563.86536 ],
        [1201.6497  ,  698.99506 , 1549.9218  ,  736.6604  ],
        [ 102.52961 , 1136.4418  , 1048.9436  , 1169.9036  ],
        [1200.8813  ,  904.489   , 1337.5482  ,  938.3957  ],
        [1200.4285  , 1174.7203  , 1301.221   , 1207.4031  ],
        [ 101.99142 , 1001.1995  , 1147.2515  , 1100.9259  ],
        [  99.619194,  900.59033 , 1144.8298  ,  968.7252  ],
        [ 151.10797 ,  764.8118  , 1145.0157  ,  865.9511  ],
        [ 101.99142 , 1001.1995  , 1147.2515  , 1100.9259  ],
        [ 181.81079 ,  225.89566 , 1143.6312  ,  294.82135 ]],
       dtype=float32)]


Each array of the array (or list of list) is a page of the document.
So, in each, i want to do OCR to the bounding boxes.
The problem is that they are not in order. And I want to order them as a human would read. Maybe it seams easy to think. At some point, it is.
If the document has only a colum, we can order them by height and that´s it. But then we can have 2 columns, maybe is still affordable. Get the mean of the Y´s and divide.
The point is that I don´t know the next format. (even in the same document, some times the columns and layout change)
So I want to order them in the more flexible and realistic way.
Ideas I had:

Order by height
Order by height and length or mean columns
Clusters(I tried DBSCAN to do clusters about the columns but
accuracy order is less than hught and length)

